# Save multiple inputs to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to save multiple inputs to localStorage. I used a 'for' loop for this purpose, but it saved the same value for all three inputs. I want the separate `foreach` values, not all of them at once:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var j = document.getElementsByName('emploi').length;
    var i;

    for(i=0; i<=j; i++) {

      var x = document.getElementsByName('emploi')[i];

      x.value = localStorage['emploi'];

      x.onchange = function() {
        localStorage['emploi'] = this.value;
      }
    }
  });
</script>

<!--Html-->

<!--SALE-->
<input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Sale'>

<!--les prof-->
<input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Professeur'>

<!--les classes-->
<input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Class'>
```

Comment: Tip: Think about what `localStorage['emploi'] = this.value;` does.

Comment: its like storing the first values in a localstorage,and this code is going to lay out that storage in the required input

Comment: localStorage['emploi'] = localStorage.employ. You are always editing the same value. And! for take an item from localStorage, you need localStorage.getItem() y .setItem() for take him

Comment: One more thing, you are doing  document.getElementsByName('emploi')[i]; In every loop, it will be better if you take that outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a JSON.stringified object instead of a simple string value otherwise you are using the same value for all 3

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // parse stored JSON if it exists otherwise an empty object 
  var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emploi') || '{}');

  var inputs = document.getElementsByName('emploi');


  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var x = inputs[i];
    x.value = values[i] || '';// stored value if it exists or empty string

    x.onchange = function() {
      // assign value to the object above
      values[i] = this.value;
      // store updated version of object
      localStorage.setItem('emploi', JSON.stringify(values));
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: i understand what you want me to get,but i try it out, the data is going empty after refreshing the page :/

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/05af3sL5/ Click "Run" after you edit or completely refresh whole page

Comment: Note that using same name is strange

Comment: i run it yours is doing well mine is not..... By the same name i was trying to treat all inputs as an array by the 'getElementsByName' thats why

Comment: no ,really its confused me here:/, i appreciate your answer btw you prove it ,so its my own problem here much respect man

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your main issue is knowing how to save data to localStorage. You need to rewrite your code based on the syntax below.

- Syntax for SAVING data to localStorage:

`localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

- Syntax for READING data from localStorage:

`const lastname = localStorage.getItem("key");`

- Syntax for REMOVING data from localStorage:

`localStorage.removeItem("key");`

Comment: what the 'key' and 'value' should contain in my situation ?

Comment: You need a unique key for every <input /> you have to set that. And the value it's input.value

Comment: @TSDI Pigier The key is a name (variable). It can be `mydata` for example.

Comment: done man i will try it out and give you the news by  VALIDATION this answer